# a funny issue in this horizontal-menu css

Tags: css, hover

I'm doing this "easy horizontal menu" but I'm facing a funny issue...

Dont know the easiest-way how to solve this problem: if I should use css or jquery (maybe too overkill)

U have **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/yoniGeek/RGd2P/)** an ex. : What I want to do is to hover on every link and hide its side-borders. At the moment I'm getting some extra-width out the hovered-area (the borders) It gets more complex for the 2-links inside  the nav if u are following me.

I dont know if I'd use images for the text and borders and hide them every time I hover them or?

Any thoughs how I should achieve this design?

Thank you

```
 <div class="Main">

        <ul>
            <li><a><p class="borders">film</p></a></li>
            <li><a><p class="borders">film</p></a></li>
            <li><a><p class="borders">film</p></a></li>
            <li><a><p class="borders">film</p></a></li>

        </ul>




    </div>
```

the css:

```
 <style>

      .Main{ width: 900px; margin: auto;}
      .Main ul{ overflow: hidden;}
      .Main ul li{ float: left; list-style: none}
      .Main ul li a{
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
          background: #ffa07a;
          display: block;
      }

      .Main ul li a p{
          text-align: center;
          position: relative;
          top:40px;

      }
      .Main ul li a:hover{ background: #7cfc00; }
      .borders{
          border-right: 2px solid #7cfc00;

      }

    </style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if I understood your problem correctly, but is this what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/RGd2P/1/

```
.Main ul li a:hover{
    background: #7cfc00;
    margin-left:-2px;
    width:101px;
    padding-left:1px;
}
```

Comment: thanks! is it possible to make the  :hover-effect visible for development purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You don't get extra width. This is the [CSS3 standard behavior](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#size-and-position-details):

```
'left'
+ 'margin-left'
+ 'border-left-width'
+ 'padding-left'
+ 'width'                   /* 100 px, bad - use 98 instead */
+ 'padding-right'
+ 'border-right-width'      /*  +2 px            +2 */
+ 'margin-right'
+ 'right'
                              =                =
= width of containing block /* 102 px,          100 */
```

If you want to set the containing block to a fixed size, then use formula above to calculate its width. Also, try to keep your markup as simple as possible and keep it semantically correct ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RGd2P/3/)):

```
<div class="Main">
    <ul>
        <li><a>film</a></li>
        <li><a>film</a></li>
        <li><a>film</a></li>
        <li><a>film</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
.Main{
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
}
.Main ul{
    width:400px;
    margin:auto;
    list-style: none;
}
.Main ul li{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 98px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ffa07a;    
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 2px solid #7cfc00;
}

.Main ul li a{    
    display:block;
    margin-top:40%;
}
.Main ul li:hover{ background: #7cfc00; }
```

Comment: thanks for yr information. By the way is it possible to make the :hover-effect visible for development purpose?

Answer (score 1):

With a few tricks here and there you can achieve it. I got rid of the `p` tags and reworked the css code. Take a look http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/k4mcr/

Answer (score 0):

just add p tag after a tag in hover... like this

```
.Main ul li a p:hover{ background: #7cfc00;width: 100px; }
```

thanks